# No route found for local appium server while automating Android app with Appium2.0

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop, appium-java

I am new to Mobile Automation. I am trying to setup Appium2.0 in my windows machine but I am running into the below issues as attached. Can someone please help?

[image]

[image]

I am trying to run the Appium server locally using the below url but always end up getting 404 error as shown in the screenshot:
URL: http://192.168.0.83:4723/ or http://127.0.0.1:4723/

Comment: why are you opening it from the browser, its returning 404 because of that. 
I don't think you understand how to use appium

Comment: Got it.. I was able to eventually figure out and was able to run the program successfully.. Thanks @mosaad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should use appium server.
You should write a script/code file that uses appium and talks with the appium server using the URL appium is giving you.

for example, code in python to connect to android device:

```
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.android.uiautomator2.base import UiAutomator2Options
    desired_capabilities = {
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'platformVersion': '11.0',  # Update this to match the Android version of your emulator
        'deviceName': 'Pixel_7_API_30',  # Update this to match the AVD name of your emulator
        'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'noReset': True,
        'noSign': True,
        'avd': 'Pixel_7_API_30',
    }
options = UiAutomator2Options()
options.load_capabilities(desired_capabilities)
appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the snippet code, I wrote my first appium code and was able to successfully execute the code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To launch the app in windows

```js
   public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Windows");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Windows");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "PCNAME");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "path//of//your//app");
        URL appiumServerURL = new URL("http://localhost:4723");
        driver = new WindowsDriver(appiumServerURL, capabilities);
        softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    }
```